# Magento removing a block for certain products

Tags: magento

I am using a block "block_product_primary_bottom" on 98% of my products. however one the other 2% I want to have it removed, since it will only be about 4 products, I don't see the need to create a custom layout. Is there a way when creating the product to remove the block in the design. 
I have tried:

```
<reference name="product.info">
   <remove name="block_product_primary_bottom"/>
</reference>
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the right way to do it.

I tried this in product design, as a test, and it removed the media block (*I'm using 1.9.3.6*):

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <remove name="product.info.media" />
</reference>
```

Also, you don't need to reference `product.info`, the name alone is descriptive enough to remove it:

```
<remove name="product.info.media" />
```

Make sure you are referencing the block name and **not** the block alias (`as="..."`). Referencing the alias won't work.

Comment: If this doesn't help, please update your question with some more information (*Magento version, your layout xml that adds the block, anything else that might be helpful*) and I'll take another look.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove it for some particular products only, you can do this from admin panel. Edit that particular product, now in design tab add below code for **Custom Layout Update**

```
<remove name="block_product_primary_bottom" />
```